# How do you use WCF Service in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asp.net-core

I have a wcf service link given to me, and have generated the client code for that using the Svcutil. But the problem lies when I try to use it in my ASP.Net Core project, it's giving me the error:

The type or namespace name 'ExtensibleDataObject' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime.Serialization' (Are you missing an assemble reference?)

Are there any workaround for this?

Comment: .NET Core does not support WCF out of the box. However, there are libraries like https://github.com/dotnet/wcf

Comment: Please check the answer here: Calling a SOAP service in .net Core https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625444/calling-a-soap-service-in-net-core

Comment: Try this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide

Answer (score 0):

You can connect using the HttpClient. Here are examples connecting to a SOAP and a REST service.

[Call a WCF service with a HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38738577/call-a-wcf-service-with-a-httpclient)

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2017/09/19/wcf-consume-wcf-rest-service-by-httpclient/